# #Errno 2 No such file or directory. Visual Studio Code on WinOS

Tags: python, file, text

I am trying to read a txt file on my python (app.py) file

I have already tried:

```
x = open("rickross.txt", "r")
y  = x.read()
x.close()

print(y)
```

I also tried using:

```
x = open("c:\Users\Vic\Documents\Py Files\files\rickross.txt", "r")
y  = x.read()
x.close()

print(y)
```

Please, what else can I do???

Comment: I keep getting this error Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
                                      [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rickross.txt'

Comment: You can try to troubleshoot what is happening by listing what is in a directory with `os.listdir()`

Comment: The easiest solution would be to use forward slashes (```/```) instead of back slashes (```\```) in the file path.

Comment: I just tried it using the forward-slash(/) and it worked. Thank you! @Chillie

Comment: How can I do that? @Jona